# Why does my IDE say my piece of code isnt extending a method of its superclass, even though it is?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA for my recent coding in java, especially Minecraft.

I tried extending the class AbstractSkeletonEntity which is an abstract class with one particular method that has been trouble for me recently:

```
abstract SoundEvent getStepSound();
```

in my own code, I try overriding the method:

```
public class SkeletonKnightEntity extends AbstractSkeletonEntity {



public boolean SkeletonCanSpawn = true;

public SkeletonKnightEntity(EntityType<? extends AbstractSkeletonEntity> entityType, World world) {
    super(entityType, world);

}

protected SoundEvent getAmbientSound() {
    return SoundEvents.ENTITY_WITHER_SKELETON_AMBIENT;
}

protected SoundEvent getHurtSound(DamageSource source) {
    return SoundEvents.ENTITY_WITHER_SKELETON_HURT;
}

protected SoundEvent getDeathSound() {
    return SoundEvents.ENTITY_WITHER_SKELETON_DEATH;
}

@Override
protected void playStepSound(BlockPos pos, BlockState state) {
    this.playSound(this.getStepSound(), 0.15F, 1.0F);
}

@Override
protected SoundEvent getStepSound() { return SoundEvents.ENTITY_WITHER_SKELETON_STEP;}
//^ here is the error

@Override
public void attack(LivingEntity target, float pullProgress) {

}
@Override
public void tickMovement() {
    super.tickMovement();
}
public static DefaultAttributeContainer.Builder createSKnightAttributes(){
    return HostileEntity.createHostileAttributes()

            .add(EntityAttributes.GENERIC_MOVEMENT_SPEED, 0.25D)
            .add(EntityAttributes.GENERIC_FOLLOW_RANGE, 30)
            .add(EntityAttributes.GENERIC_ATTACK_DAMAGE, 1)

            ;
}
@Override
protected void initGoals() {
    this.goalSelector.add(3, new FleeEntityGoal(this, WolfEntity.class, 6.0F, 1.0D, 1.2D));
    this.goalSelector.add(5, new WanderAroundFarGoal(this, 1.0D));
    this.goalSelector.add(6, new LookAtEntityGoal(this, PlayerEntity.class, 8.0F));
    this.goalSelector.add(6, new LookAroundGoal(this));
    this.targetSelector.add(1, new RevengeGoal(this, new Class[0]));
    this.targetSelector.add(2, new FollowTargetGoal(this, PlayerEntity.class, true));
    this.targetSelector.add(3, new FollowTargetGoal(this, IronGolemEntity.class, true));
    this.targetSelector.add(3, new FollowTargetGoal(this, TurtleEntity.class, 10, true, false, TurtleEntity.BABY_TURTLE_ON_LAND_FILTER));
}
protected void dropEquipment(DamageSource source, int lootingMultiplier, boolean allowDrops) {
    super.dropEquipment(source, lootingMultiplier, allowDrops);
    Entity entity = source.getAttacker();
    if (entity instanceof CreeperEntity) {
        CreeperEntity creeperEntity = (CreeperEntity)entity;
        if (creeperEntity.shouldDropHead()) {
            creeperEntity.onHeadDropped();
            this.dropItem(Items.SKELETON_SKULL);
        }
    }

}
}
```

the IDE tells me for the code to work, I have to declare SkeletonKnightEntity abstract or implement the abstract method getStepSound() which I already did. when I try overriding the getStepSound() method, it tells me it's not overriding anything from the superclass. does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: This is the problem: `SoundEvent getStepSound();` (package visibility) != `protected SoundEvent getStepSound()`.

Answer (score 4):

When you override a method, you can *increase* its visibility, but you can't decrease it. You took a `public` method and overrode it with a `protected` one. That isn't allowed. The superclass promised that that method can be called from anywhere, and you gave it a method that didn't meet that promise. Remove the `protected` modifier and you'll be just fine.

You didn't explicit say, so I'll include this for completeness. I'm assuming the parent method is `public`. If it really doesn't have a modifier (like your question shows), then it gets the default visibility of "package-private". A package-private method can't be accessed at all outside of the package it was defined in, so if the writer of that class made an abstract package-private method, then they intended that no one outside of the defining package is allowed to subclass their class, so you won't be allowed to either.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/2288659) for a summary of the visibility options in Java.

Comment: thanks, but that didnt seem to work. still says that i'm not overriding it

Comment: I just realized an incompleteness in my answer. Please see the second paragraph I just added. Is the method you're overriding package-private?

Comment: yeah it is package private

Comment: Then unfortunately you're slightly out of luck. The author of the class intended that it only be overridden within the same package (kind of like the `sealed` keyword in Kotlin or Scala), and there's no way around that.

Comment: could i create my own class that copies it and use that?